# How to send Parse object field from one class to another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I want to make such thing:
On one ViewControleer I'm making a query to Parse.com, where I'm sending objects fields to Label.Text. By clicking one button objects randomly changes, by clicking another one- next ViewController is opening. Just imagine Tinder - on the first VC I swiping girls, on the new one chat is opening, with the girl's name in the head of the NavigatorItem

So I want to send Object Field "Name" that I'm using in that view to another without other query.
I don't know, whether I can do it via segue, or protocol. Can U somehow help me with implementation?

here is the code of my random function

```
func retriveJobData() {
    var query: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Jobs")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("AUeuvj0zk2") {
        (newJobObject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil && newJobObject != nil {
            println(newJobObject)

            if let newJobObject = newJobObject {

            self.PrcieTextField.text = newJobObject["jobPrice"] as? String

            self.DateTextField.text = newJobObject["jobDate"] as? String

            self.DescriptionTextField.text = newJobObject["jobDescription"] as? String

            }
        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to send newJobObject["jobName"] to NavigatorItemName of another ViewController

Answer (score 0):

you can override prepareForSegue for this purpose:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "yourSegueIdentifier") {
        // pass data to next view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some method that triggers a push to the new viewController and that you're using the storyboard, call `performSegue` using the identifier you set up in the storyboard

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("identifier", sender: nil)
}
```

Then override `prepareForSegue` and pass in the string

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
        controller.jobName = someWayThatYouRetrieveNewJobObjectName
}
```

Then in `ViewController` ensure you have a property for jobName

```
var jobName:String! //declare this as an optional instead if needed
```

And set the navigation title

```
navigationItem.title = jobName
```